# ¿Cómo valido lo que el usuario escribe con una posicion de una matriz?

Tags: c++, poo

Tengo un proyecto sobre un programa de compra de tickets de un cine. El usuario deberá escoger su asiento de acuerdo a un nombre y un número.

Necesito crear un método que valide el asiento escogido por el usuario y le cambie su estado a ocupado.

---

[image]

---

`A1` es la posición `mat[0][0]`.

Comment: [¿Qué has intentado?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Bienvenida al foro. ¿Qué tienes hecho o has intentado hasta la fecha? Publicar ese código ayuda a que las respuestas sean acordes a tu código. Además, este foro está orientado a la resolución de dudas, no ha resolver ejercicios, por lo que publicar parte de tu código facilita que la gente te ayude.

Comment: Bienvenida @Estefania. Quizás te sea útil revisar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Sería genial que puedas [edit] tu  pregunta para agregar más detalles específicos.

Answer (score 2):

Yo crearía una matriz (estática, ya que el tamaño siempre es el mismo), y almacenaría en cada posición si esta ocupada o no. Por ejemplo la inicializo a 0 para saber que no esta ocupada, y, más tarde, si alguien reserva pongo un -1.

```
//creo la matriz y la inicializo a 0
int matriz[10][6];
for(i=0; i<fil; i++){
  for(j=0; j<col; j++){
    matriz[i][j]=0;
  }
}
```

Esto es lo que tendría que hacer tu función:

Luego leo dos variables del teclado, una sería la letra y otra el número. Si la letra no es {a,b,c,d,e,f} vuelves a pedir la letra, y lo mismo para el número (tiene que ser desde 1 hasta 10).

```
// Este while es por si la silla ya esta ocupada, 
// se vuelven a pedir los datos.
bool reservaRealizada=false;
while (!reservaRealizada){

   char letra;
   cout << "Teclee la letra";
   cin >> letra;
   while (letra!='A' && letra!='B' && letra!='C' && letra!='D' 
          && letra!='E' && letra!='F'){
      cout << "Letra no válida, vuelva a repetir:";
      cin >> letra; 
   }
}
```

Y lo mismo para el número.

```
int numero;
cout << "Teclee el numero";
cin >> numero;
...
...
```

Una vez que la letra y el número sean correctos, compruebas esa posicion en la matriz:

```
  int fila;
  int columna;

  columna = numero-1;

  if (letra == 'A')
      fila = 0;
  else if (letra == 'B')
      fila = 1;
  ...
  ...

  // si esta vacia, ponemos un -1
  if (matriz[fila][columna]==0){
     matriz[fila][columna]==-1
     cout << "Reserva realizada con éxito";
     reservaRealizada = true;
  }else{
    cout << "Asiento ocupado, intente con otro";
  }
} // fin del while(!reservaRealizada)
```

Si la reserva no se ha realizado volvería a entrar en el while para pedir de nuevo otra silla.

Espero que te sirva.
Saludos.

Comment: Correcto, hay que cambiar la condición 'o' por 'y'. 
Gracias eferion, no se como no me he dado cuenta de esto, 
la verdad que no estoy comprobando mi código en ningún IDE ni lo he probado.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, ya que se ha publicado una solución voy a poner yo otra alternativa usando la STL.

Lo primero es declarar una función auxiliar para evitar repetir código, aunque sea poco:

```
bool EnRango(int valor, int min, int max)
{
    return ( valor >= min && valor < max);
}
```

Y ahora la parte de la reserva de asientos:

```
const int Filas = 6;
const int Columnas = 10;

std::array<std::array<bool,Columnas>,Filas> matriz { false };

int fila,columna;

while(true)
{
  char letra;
  std::cout << "Introduce las coordenadas del asiento: ";
  std::cin >> letra >> columna;

  // letra a mayúsculas
  letra = std::toupper(letra);
  fila = letra-'A';
  columna--;

  if( !EnRango(fila,0,Filas) )
    std::cout << "Letra incorrecta\n";
  else if( !EnRango(columna,0,Columnas) )
    std::cout << "Columna incorrecta\n";
  else if( matriz[fila][columna] )
    std::cout << "Asiento ocupado\n";
  else
  {
    matriz[fila][columna] = true;
    std::cout << "Asiento reservado correctamente\n";
    break;
  }
}
```

¿Por qué usar `std::array` en vez de `bool matriz[Filas][Columnas]`? `std::array` es un contenedor de la STL que dispone de muchas características que facilitan la programación, como los iteradores o métodos que indican el número de elementos.

¿Por qué usar el tipo `bool` en vez de `int`?
Porque salvo que se modifique la pregunta, lo único que importa es indicar si un asiento está reservado o no y esto se representa con una variable booleana.

Usar el tipo correcto en cada caso mejora la legibilidad del programa y ayuda a prevenir errores.

El código compila perfectamente en C++11 en adelante.

Un saludo.